# English Translation of a French Theorem by Brezis

Tags: functional-analysis, variational-analysis, translation-request, mathematical-french

I am interested in an English translation of the French "THEOREME 24" in ["Équations et inéquations non linéaires dans les espaces vectoriels en dualité"](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_1968__18_1_115_0/) by Haïm Brézis.

It states

> **THEOREME 24.** — Soient $X$ un convexe compact de $E$, $A$ une application pseudo-monotone de $X$ dans $F$ et $\phi$ une  fonction convexe S.C.I. de $X$ dans $]-\infty, +\infty]$ non  identiquement égale à $+\infty$.
> Alors pour  tout $f\in F$,  il  existe $u\in X$ tel que
> $$(f, v - u) - (Au, v - u) \leq \phi(v) - \phi(u) \quad\forall v \in X.\quad(4.1)$$
> L'ensemble des solutions de (4.1) est compact ; il est convexe compact lorsque $A$ est monotone hémicontinu.
>
> Si  de  plus, $(Ax  - A y , x - y ) > 0, \forall x, y \in X , x \neq y$,  alors  la solution  de  (4.1)  est  unique.

Prior to THEOREME 24, he states

> Soient $E$ et $F$ deux espaces vectoriels sur $\mathbf R$ mis en dualité par une forme  bilinéaire $(f, u), f\in F , u \in E$.
> On supposera dans la suite que $E$ est muni d'une topologie d'espace vectoriel topologique, plus fine que $\sigma(E , F)$ et que $F$ est muni de la topologie $\sigma(F , E)$.

My best attempt at translating this:

Let $E$ and $F$ be two vector spaces on $\mathbb R$ that are brought into duality by a bilinear form $\langle f, u \rangle$ for $f\in F, u\in E$.
We suppose, that $E$ is equipped with a finer topology than $\sigma(E,F)$ and $F$ is equipped with the topology $\sigma(F,E)$.

**Theorem 24.** — Let $X$ be a compact, convex subset of $E$, let $A: X\to F$ be a pseudo-monotone operator and let $\phi: X \to (-\infty, \infty]$ be convex and lower semi-continuous with $\phi(x)=\infty$ does not hold for all $x\in X$.
Then for all $f\in F$ there exists some $u\in X$ such that
$$\langle f, v - u\rangle - \langle A(u), v - u\rangle \leq \phi(v) - \phi(u) \quad\forall v \in X.\quad(4.1)$$
The set $S$ of solutions to (4.1) is compact; if $A$ is monotone and hemicontinuous, $S$ is even convex and compact.

If $\langle Ax  - A y , x - y \rangle > 0$ holds for all $x, y \in X , x \neq y$, then the solution is unique.

**Edit1:** I adjusted the translation as proposed in a comment.

**Edit2:** I just realized, that the definition of **pseudo-monotone** is also not straight-forward to me and a translation would be great.

> **Definition F.** — Soit $X$ un sous-ensemble de $E$. On dit qu'une
> application $A$ de $X$ dans $F$ est *pseudo-monotone* si elle vérifie les deux propriétés suivantes:
>
> ($\text{PM}_1$) Pour tout filtre $u_i$ porté par un ensemble compact de X tel que $u_i \to u$ dans X et $\lim \sup (Au_i , u_i - u) \leq 0$ on a
> $$(Au , u - v) \leq \lim \inf(Au_i, u_i - v) \quad\forall v \in X .$$
>
> ($\text{PM}_2$) Pour tout $v\in X$, l'application $u \to (A u, u - v)$ est bornée intérieurement sur les sous-ensembles compacts de $X$.
>
> **Remarque.** — Si la topologie induite par E sur les sous-ensembles compacts de X est métrisable, alors la propriété ($\text{PM}_1$) est equivalente à la même propriété formulée pour des suites.

My best translation to this would be:

**Definition F.** — Let $X\subseteq E$. An operator $A: X \to F$ is called *pseudo-monotone* if it fulfills the following two conditions:

($\text{PM}_1$) For any filter $u_i$ on a compact subset of $X$ with $u_i\to u$ in $X$ and $\lim\sup\langle A(u_i), u_i - u \rangle \leq 0$ we have
$$\langle A(u) , u - v\rangle \leq \lim \inf\langle A(u_i), u_i - v\rangle \quad\forall v \in X .$$
($\text{PM}_2$) For all $v\in X$, the mapping $u \mapsto \langle A(u), u - v\rangle$ is bounded from below on all compact subsets of $X$.

**Remark.** — If the topology induced on $E$ by the compact subsets of $X$ is metrizable, the property ($\text{PM}_1$) is equivalent to the same properties formulized for sequences.

Additional questions:

**Q1**: What does $A(u_i)$ mean, if $u_i$ is a filter? How can we calculate with it as if it was an element of $F$?

**Q2**: A "filter $u_i$ on a compact subset of $X$" means that all elements of the filter are subsets of one compact subset of $X$, right?

**Q3**: Is ($\text{PM}_2$) equivalent to the following? For all $v\in X$ and all compact subsets $C\subseteq X$ there is some $M\in\mathbb R$ with $\langle A(u),u-v\rangle\geq M$ for all $u\in C$.

Comment: Looks good. The definition of *monotone hémicontinu* can be found [here](https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/MathModel/enseignement/polycopies/ledret-chapitre7.pdf) (déf 13), hopefully that will resolve your "lower (?)"

Comment: @MatthewTowers so "monotone hémicontinu" means "monotone" and "hémicontinu", right?

Comment: I think so but maybe a functional analyst can confirm